# ListView renderRow pass state to prop

Tags: listview, react-native

I'm trying to set scrollY prop with a state value updated by the onscroll function. Is this the correct way of doing this? I need to pass the scrollY offset to my component. I'm able to get a value on my component but it doesn't update as I scroll.

```
renderRow: function (rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return (
       <VideoCard key={rowData.id} data={rowData} rowid={rowID} autoplay={this.state.autoplay} scrollY={this.state.contentOffset} navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
    );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The component that has this `renderRow` method should have a method of setting its own state.

Then, you should pass that method over to your `VideoCard` component as a prop.

Comment: This is what I'm doing. But there is actually a bug with cloneWithRowsandSeconds. I decided to use cloneWithRows and works fine.